# VMWARE ESXI 7 - 2 NIC's Network Config. 1 for VM provisioning 1 for Management?

Tags: networking, vmware, esxi

Good day lads!
I'm somewhat new to any "non-out of the box configurations" in ESXI. I've used it on and off but never played around that much with it. Been more focused on Hyper-V.
I have a Dell Powerdege T630 as a homelab server recently bought and installed ESXI 7.0. It has 2 NICs and was planning to have them configured 1 for ESXI Management and 1 for VM Network Provisioning.

At the moment I have the default network configuration:

- [Port Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbook.png)
- [Virtual Switches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb0C4.png)
- [Physical NICs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du3ST.png)
- [VMKernel NICs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKQQ8.png)
- [TCP/IP Stacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82rj5.png)

So, I'm wondering, how should I configure my network settings to achieve this?

--Long Story Short--

It has 2 NICs and I want to have them configured 1 for ESXI Management and 1 for VM Network Provisioning. Since at the moment I think 1 NIC is used for both management and VM Network Provisioning.

Comment: @harrymc I edited and reworded the text to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here:

> I would: First NIC = vSwtch0 = vmk0 for Mgmt. Sec NIC = vSwitch1 = VM Port Group for VM traffic. Done
>
> Now if you want more flexibility and resiliency: BOTH NICs = vSwitch0
> = NIC2 Active, NIC1 Standby vmk0 = Mgmt + Override Teaming+Failover screen to set NIC1 Active and NIC2 Standby. Port Group(s) = VM traffic
> and no override needed due to vSwitch default. This method has the
> advantage of separating the traffic, but if you have a port failure on
> NIC1 or NIC2, the functions on the failed port will simply move over
> to the surviving port. (The functions on the Surviving port that were
> there in the first place do nothing and keep on working).

Source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/xuw4d3/vmware_esxi_7_2_nics_network_config_1_for_vm/

Cheers!